# Android AOSP build error with third party lib like Firebase - "appname" depends on undefined module "com.google.firebase_firebase-core"

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source, android-developer-api, android-rom

I'm trying to build a custom apk into an AOSP build which uses some external libs like Firebase,  Glide etc.

Studying the sample projects in AOSP and others like LineageOS, dependencies are added into Android.bp like so, for example:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
```

**Android.bp**

```
android_app {
    ...
    static_libs: [
      "com.google.android.material_material"
      "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview"
      "androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout"
    ],

    srcs: ["src/**/*.kt"],
    resource_dirs: ["res"],
}
```

For Firebase and Glide, I've tried adding to `Android.bp` like so:

```
android_app {
    ...
    static_libs: [
      "com.google.android.material_material",
      "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
      "androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
      "com.google.firebase_firebase-core",
      "com.github.bumptech.glide_glide"
    ],

    srcs: ["src/**/*.kt"],
    resource_dirs: ["res"],
}
```

but this doesn't work, throw errors like so:

```
error: vendor/manufacturer/appname/Android.bp:1:1 "appname" depends on undefined module "com.google.firebase_firebase-core"
error: vendor/manufacturer/appname/Android.bp:1:1 "appname" depends on undefined module "com.github.bumptech.glide_glide"
```

Also noticed in `Android.bp` how the naming convention for `constraintlayout` is different than `recyclerview`, why is it not a `.` but a `-` and where's all this naming convention documented on how to should dependencies be added?

Where can I find more doc on how to add third party libs, any help pointers is much appreciated!

Build env:

```
Ubuntu 18.04
AOSP - 10_r39
```

Answer (score 1):

In AOSP, you can't use the "Gradle way" of just adding it into `build.gradle`, and having build tools fetch the module from a repository ( j`Center/ Maven Central etc.`).
For AOSP you'll have to add those dependent modules in the build system yourself.
In your case, create two modules ( `com.google.firebase_firebase-core` and `com.github.bumptech.glide_glide` ), add Android.mk or Android.bp for them ( with the module name that you want, and then you can refer to them in your Android.bp.

For example, see how it's added for `com.google.android.material_material` :
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:prebuilts/sdk/current/extras/material-design-x/Android.bp

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, that really helps, researching further on how to get Firebase to work

Comment: I've asked a separate question specific to Firebase as I don't want to mixed up the two question, let me know if you have any guidance around this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63072643/aosp-firebase-initialisation-error-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized-in-this-proce

Comment: I don't know a lot about Firebase specifically, haven't worked with it in years. BUT, since the error is Firebase SDK specific question, then look on what's different when building via google. Maybe you didn't add the google-services.json or some other configuration file when bulding via AOSP too.

Comment: As a side-note, if integrating firebase into build system proves to be too cumbersome, you can always just generate the APK normally, and sign it with platform keys. That way it will have signature level permissions. If you need access to hidden APIs when using Android studio you can use https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api , or just modify source code ( remove @hide where necessary) and generate SDK youself ( make sdk )

Comment: Yes, the reason I want to get it to work with the build is because it uses system level permissions. I'll have to explore the hidden-api method, thanks for your help!